# Can I get all command line arguments that are not used by Qt?

Tags: python-3.x, qt, arguments, qt5, command-line-arguments

I am developing a Qt application that I want to accept command line arguments.
I do not want to use a `QCommandLineParser` with `QCommandLineOptions`, because it does not support choices like the builtin `argparse`, and because it requires the `QApplication` to be initialized *before* the `QCommandLineParser`.
But, I cannot simply use the arguments from `sys.argv`, because these contain Qt-specific arguments such as `--style`, too.
Has Qt a builtin function to give me just these arguments that are not used by Qt itself, or will I have to filter them out myself one by one ?

I did find `QCoreApplication.arguments()`, but that doesn't fit my needs. Quote from [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#arguments):

> On Unix, this list is built from the argc and argv parameters passed to the constructor in the main() function

From that, I deduce that the list of arguments returned by `QCoreApplication.arguments` still contains Qt-specific options such as `--style`.

Comment: Haven't checked but, does the `QApplication` constructor not remove recognized args from `sys.argv`?

Comment: @G.M. omg it _does_ remove them ! But why isn't this stated in the docs ? Thanks anyways - if you make it an answer, I'll be happy to accept and upvote it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment, the code...

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
```

will remove recognized args from `sys.argv`, after which you can perform your own processing of `sys.argv` as you please.

Note that while this doesn't appear to be stated explicitly in the `python` documentation the [`c++`  docs.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#QApplication) state...

> **Note**: argc and argv might be changed as Qt removes command line arguments that it recognizes.